# Rank arrays numbers in Python

Tags: python

In Python, how can we provide a function that takes as input:

- A number
- An array

and then provides as an output the rank of the
number in the array? If the number is not part of the array then it should be the rank of the number lower than the value given.

For example, if the function was given

- the values 7.23 and
  `[1.2,4.3,5,7.23,63.1]`, then the rank should be 4.
- the values 3.5 and
  `[1.2,4.3,5,7.23,63.1]`, then the rank should be 1.
- the values 100 and
  `[1.2,4.3,5,7.23,63.1]`, then the rank should be 5.

Comment: Is the list (array) always monotonic increasing?

Answer (score 1):

Assuming the list/array is sorted, you can use [`bisect.bisect_right`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/bisect.html#bisect.bisect_right):

```
from bisect import bisect_right
bisect_right(array, number)
```

Example:

```
bisect_right([1.2,4.3,5,7.23,63.1], 7.23)
4

bisect_right([1.2,4.3,5,7.23,63.1], 3.5)
1

bisect_right([1.2,4.3,5,7.23,63.1], 100)
5
```

Answer (score 0):

I think its best to try and solve this question yourself first to get some practice, but if you have tried and you are now looking for a solution below is a simple way of doing so.

Note the below solution assumes the array is sorted. The `elif` also isn't necessary due to the return above (can replace it with `if`), but for readability I have included it

```py
def getRank(arr, value):
  for index, arrVal in enumerate(arr):
    if arrVal == value:
      return index + 1
    elif arrVal > value:
      return index

  return len(arr)
```

Another note, this is a simple O(n) solution as you have to at worst iterate through the whole array. Assuming the list is sorted a binary tree solution could be done with a complexity of O(logn)